# Problem calculating expectation using law of total expectation

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I'm confusing myself with conditional expectation and could really use your help! I am trying to calculate an expectation that arises in the context of doing variational inference. However, the expectation doesn't match what Monte Carlo gives me, so I know something is wrong. I have an idea of where things might be going off, but I'm not 100% sure.

The expectation is:

$\mathbb{E}_\mathbf{F} [\log [p(Y = 0) + p(Y = 1) \prod_{i=1}^{N}p(M_i=m_i|F_i, Y=1)]]$.

I hope this is clear so far. As-is, this is hard to evaluate since it is an expectation over the $N$ random variables $F_1, ..., F_N$. So I thought I could use the law of total expectation. Writing the expectation as:

$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{F}}[g(\mathbf{F})]$,

by the law of total expectation, this is equal to:

$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{F}}[g(\mathbf{F} | Y = 0)] p(Y = 0) + \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{F}}[g(\mathbf{F} | Y = 1)]p(Y = 1)$.

*Note: Did I go wrong here already? Do the expectations have to be taken over $\mathbf{F}|Y = 0$ and $\mathbf{F}|Y = 1$ instead?*

*If* this isn't wrong, then things simplify quite a lot. For the first term, since we condition on $Y = 0$, the expectation simplifies to:

$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{F}}[\log [p(Y = 0 | Y = 0) + p(Y = 1 | Y = 0) \prod_{i=1}^{N} p(M_i = m_i | F_i, Y = 1, Y = 0)]] = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{F}}[\log [1 + 0]] = 0$

And, by similar reasoning, the second expectation becomes:

$\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \mathbb{E}_{F_i} \log p(M_i = m_i | F_i, Y = 1)$,

which is great because it's a sequence of 1D expectations. But as I mentioned, this seems to be wrong so I'd appreciate someone pointing out what exactly is off here. Thanks in advance!